# Is "realize" a synonym for "implement"?

Tags: synonyms, false-friends

Many of my colleagues use the word *realize* in the sense of *implement* (as in "software realization" or "I didn't realize this function") It looks like these are false friends in both [French](https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/implement) and [German](https://translate.google.com/#en/de/implement). However, the use is so widespread that I'm having doubts whether it's legitimate. A few examples:

[CAN Specification](http://www.bosch-semiconductors.de/media/ubk_semiconductors/pdf_1/canliteratur/can2spec.pdf), page 1:

> These applications can be realized with CAN more comfortably [...]

[Autosar OS specification](http://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/files/releases/4-2/software-architecture/system-services/standard/AUTOSAR_SWS_OS.pdf), page 121:

> The RTE realizes the service on client side by mapping the client/server call to a sender/receiver communication.

[Renesas RL78 User's manual](http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/rl78/r01uh0146ej0320_rl78g13.pdf), page 269:

> Channel 7 of unit 0 can be used to realize LIN-bus communication operating in combination with UART2 [...]

Comment: Seems like a legitimate use according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realize)

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't mean that the two words are always acceptably interchangeable. 'Achieve', 'facilitate' etc might sound more natural, and 'I didn't realize this function' sounds garden-pathy if not ambiguous to a layman. Does it mean 'I didn't use this function' or 'I didn't manage to make use of this function'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is supposed to mean "I didn't *implement/create/develop* this function".

Comment: @Tarok I thought using *to realize* in sense of "to bring into concrete existence" only applied to goals, dreams etc. Can I really say that I have realized a strawberry cake last evening? I have certainly brought that cake into existence, didn't I?

Comment: You see the problem: 'realize' has a lot of senses. ELU is a general English usage website, so answers here will validly cover general usage. Registers such as that/those used by computer engineers (!) are really a separate issue; I'd suggest consulting a dedicated dictionary or glossary. A classic case of confusion is what people mean by a 'hurricane'; metereologists insist on a stricter definition than many laypersons use.

Comment: re your question about range of DO's licensed: This is always a tricky and contentious area. chef - Magazine Restaurant
www.magazine-restaurant.co.uk/the-chef/the-chef/ has: 
'Through quality selection and simple technique, excellent dishes were realised'. I'd probably read this without being startled, but 'I realized a superb strawberry cake yesterday' sounds ridiculous, as you say. This particular example is probably down to incongruous mixing of registers, but acceptability tends to be unpredictable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is my cake example general enough? Should I include it in the question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You last comment actually makes a lot of sense to me. When my colleagues say they "realized" a function, I get exactly that feeling that the wrong register is being used.

Comment: re 'Is my cake ...': It's certainly more appropriate for ELU, but doesn't really help with your computerese-related query.

Comment: Note that 'implement' is certainly not interchangeable with 'create' / 'develop'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your answers, and sorry if my question wasn't a good fit. I'll try to avoid asking domain-specific questions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that "realize" is being used (and perhaps slightly misused), in the above sense, to differentiate from "conceptualize".  When you take a concept and make it "real" you have "realized" it.

In this sense it's probably best applied to simple algorithms and the like -- you would not say that a giant skyscraper is the realization of its blueprints.

Comment: Please cite sources, 'Hot Licks'. If a rule applies to one it applies to everyone or it's not really a rule at all, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to use 'realise' in the meaning of 'create/implement', but 'implement' is most suitable, because in contemporary English word 'realise' is a synonim to 'understand'.

Comment: That's pretty much the way I use *realize* most often. Only I would say it's a synonym with *to become aware*, as in "I realized I lost my keys"