# realize or enable?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I need to know if realize is the right word in this sentence:

"Rigid connectors realize the transmission of kinematic motion from the tow bar deformation to the plates."

I want to say that i use "rigid connectors" in a simulation to transfer kinematic motions.

Could I use enable instead?

Thx for any help.

Comment: Please go to the [help] and read about writing a good question.

Comment: That's a bit clumsy even with the right word or phrase. You could say they *effect* (yes with an E), or *allow* or *enable* or *permit* -- lots of words fit there. *Realize* isn't one of them.

Comment: "Rigid connectors transmit kinematic motion from the tow bar deformation to the plates."

Comment: @Bookeater +1 for trimming the verbiage.  In the same direction, I'd suggest deleting "kinematic".  Kinematic motion seems to be the same thing as motion.

Answer (score 0):

From Macmillan online dictionary:

> [Realize
>   [3]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/realize):
>   FORMAL to achieve something that you have planned or hoped for

comes close to the technical meaning of *realize* I am familiar with: to be or provide the mechanism by which something happens. By contrast I would understand "enable" in this context to have the broader meaning of "to facilitate something happening".

So if the "Rigid connectors" pass mechanical movement from point A to point B of themselves I would suggest that "realize" is more precise than "enable".

This usage of "realize" seems to be more common in technical circles than in common parlance. See related question [Is “realize” a synonym for “implement”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321680/is-realize-a-synonym-for-implement) for further discussion and comments.